# Group by column in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this :

```
Year    Month   Item  val1 val2 val3
2011        1   A       86      
2011        1   B       17      
2012        2   B       10      
2012        2   C       1       
2013        3   A       82      
2013        3   B       89      
2011        1   A           59  
2011        1   B           75  
2012        2   B           26  
2012        2   C           77  
2013        3   A           62  
2013        3   B           78  
2011        1   A               70
2011        1   B               17
2012        2   B               15
2012        2   C               20
2013        3   A               62
2013        3   B               43
```

i want look like this :

```
Year    Month Item  val1 val2 val3
2011        1   A     86    59  70
2011        1   B     17    75  17
2012        2   B     10    26  15
2012        2   C     1     77  20
2013        3   A     82    62  62
2013        3   B     89    78  43
```

i try some query like this :

```
select year,month,item,val1,val2,val3 from table
group by year,month,item
```

but it's doesn't work
somebody can help me? thanks

Comment: What database are you using?  You'll probably want to include an aggregate function around your columns `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`.  What do you mean `it doesn't work`, do you get an error message?

Comment: @bluefeet : i use mysql, output val2 and val3, all value in val1, and val1, val3 is empty (null)

Comment: You need to use an aggregate function around those columns, like `max(val1)`, max(val2)`, etc along with your group by.

Comment: Where you have missing values - are there actually NULL's there or empty strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like what you have with some aggregate function:

```
select year,month,item,
    MAX(COALESCE(val1,0)) as val1,MAX(COALESCE(val2,0)) as val2,MAX(COALESCE(val3,0)) as val3 from table
group by year,month,item
```